# Why do some characters like brackets cause a 400 BAD REQUEST error in a Spring REST endpoint?

Tags: spring, rest, get, jackson

I'm trying to call a REST API exposed via GET method in a Spring application. When sending requests, I noticed the controller doesn't support some characters and instantly returns a 400 BAD_REQUEST error before the controller code is even executed.

Characters which reproduce the bug:

```
[]{}|\
```

All other chararacters like the following do not reproduce the bug:

```
&+<>$?!@°*~#"'/
```

Example of a working request:

```
http://localhost:8888/api?a=&b=Hello&c=&d=&e=0&f=1
```

Exemple of a non working request:

```
http://localhost:8888/api?a=&b=%5BHello&c=&d=&e=0&f=1
```

The position of the charater in the string doesn't have any effect on this bug.
This bug occurs when one of the six characters mentioned above is present in any of the string parameters.

Here is the controller code :

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Object> getEmails(
        @RequestParam(required = false, name = "a") String a,
        @RequestParam(required = false, name = "b") String b,
        @RequestParam(required = false, name = "c") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime c,
        @RequestParam(required = false, name = "d") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime d,
        @RequestParam(name = "e") Integer e,
        @RequestParam(name = "f") Integer f
) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(myService.doSomeStuff(a, b, c, d, e, f), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

We use Spring along with the following Jackson dependencies :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the URL on the client side.

`http://localhost:8083?a=asd[`

you should end up with this

`http://localhost:8083?a=asd%5B`

Clients usually provide a function for URL encoding, please check its documentation. If you are using a client like Postman for testing then you can right click in the address bar and there you have an option to encode the URL.

Some characters like `[` are considered allowed but unsafe characters and that's why encoding is needed.

**Later edit**:

I've tested your code and request and everything works fine. The only change I made was in controller method to return a String instead of a response entity.

```
@RestController
class Ctrl {
    @GetMapping
    public String getEmails(
            @RequestParam(required = false, name = "a") String a,
            @RequestParam(required = false, name = "b") String b,
            @RequestParam(required = false, name = "c") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime c,
            @RequestParam(required = false, name = "d") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime d,
            @RequestParam(name = "e") Integer e,
            @RequestParam(name = "f") Integer f
    ) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

`curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8083?a=&b=%5BHello&c=&d=&e=0&f=1'`

[image]

You can enable spring debug/trace logging and see what is happening.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. 
I already send an encoded string like the one you quote. Here is the encoded string my clients (postman and angular) send to the API : /api?a=&b=%5BHello&c=&d=&e=0&f=1
(Notice the %5BHello value for b parameter). Did I miss something in my encoding?